# JS - Merge Objects

Tags: javascript, object, merge

I need to merge/combine 4 objects inside and array.
The objects are:

```
{"field": "name","lang": "it","text": "RegoleAziendali"}
{"field": "pdf_url","lang": "it", "text": "docs/it/file.pdf"}
{"field": "name","lang": "en","text": "CompanyRules"}
{"field": "pdf_url","lang": "en", "text": "docs/en/file.pdf"}
```

Expected Result Should Be made of 2 objects merged by the language.

```
{"lang": "it","name": "RegoleAziendali","pdf_url":"docs/it/file.pdf"}
{"lang": "en","name": "CompanyRules","pdf_url":"docs/en/file.pdf"}
```

At the moment I am using array.forEach to merge two objects by lang. But I can not find a way to manipulate the values/properties. As you can see the property "field" is no longer needed in the merged objects.

Comment: Use an object whose keys are the languages, and values are the new objects. Then you can loop over the original array, adding the properties to the appropriate new objects.

Comment: What have you tried? We're not a free coding service. See [ask].

Comment: var obj={};
    
    array.forEach(function(e){
      if(e && e.lang){
        obj[e.lang] = obj[e.lang] || {};    
        for(var _k in e) obj[e.lang][_k] = e[_k]
      }
    });       
    
    return Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {return obj[key]});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you have an array, you can convert this to a grouping problem.

Group by `lang` using `reduce`.
After that take the values array of the grouped object using `Object.values`

```js
const x = [
{"field": "name","lang": "it","text": "RegoleAziendali"},
{"field": "pdf_url","lang": "it", "text": "docs/it/file.pdf"},
{"field": "name","lang": "en","text": "CompanyRules"},
{"field": "pdf_url","lang": "en", "text": "docs/en/file.pdf"}
]

const res = Object.values(x.reduce((acc,{field,lang,text}) => {
  acc[lang] = acc[lang] || {lang}
  acc[lang][field] = text
  return acc
},{}))

console.log(res)
```

the same thing can be done using a for loop

```js
const x = [{"field": "name","lang": "it","text": "RegoleAziendali"},{"field": "pdf_url","lang": "it", "text": "docs/it/file.pdf"},{"field": "name","lang": "en","text": "CompanyRules"},{"field": "pdf_url","lang": "en", "text": "docs/en/file.pdf"}]

const res = {}
for (const entry of x){
  const {field,lang,text} = entry
  res[lang] = res[lang] || {lang}
  res[lang][field] = text
}

console.log(Object.values(res))
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I wonder where you learn to code in an elegant way!

Answer (score 2):

```js
const arr = [{"field": "name","lang": "it","text": "RegoleAziendali"}, {"field": "pdf_url","lang": "it", "text": "docs/it/file.pdf"}, {"field": "name","lang": "en","text": "CompanyRules"}, {"field": "pdf_url","lang": "en", "text": "docs/en/file.pdf"}];


const ans = arr.reduce((a,{field,lang,text}) => ({...a, [lang]: {...a[lang], [field]: text, lang }}), {});

console.log(Object.values(ans));
```

Comment: Ooh, very nice approach.

Comment: I love this solution as well, though very hard to understand for me being the exact opposite of a js ninja

Comment: @MirkoNardi here I built a dictionary where the `key` is the `lang` and values are `{name,lang,pdf_url}` when it hits the same key it just updates its properties.

Comment: @Asraf Ok, now i get it! Its not as hard as it looks like after 15 minutes of reading

Answer (score 1):

To cherry-pick certain fields:

```js
const data = [
  {"field": "name","lang": "it","text": "RegoleAziendali"},
  {"field": "pdf_url","lang": "it", "text": "docs/it/file.pdf"},
  {"field": "name","lang": "en","text": "CompanyRules"},
  {"field": "pdf_url","lang": "en", "text": "docs/en/file.pdf"}
]

const lookup = (lang, field) => ({
  [field]: data.find(i=>i.lang===lang && i.field===field).text
})

console.log([...new Set(data.map(i=>i.lang))].map(lang=>({
  lang, ...lookup(lang, 'name'), ...lookup(lang, 'pdf_url')
})))
```